# How i can open PNG w alpha channel, if he is white

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, png, alpha, opencv

I have a lot images like this:
[Screenshot from ImageMagick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EU1bu.png)

When I open it image in cv2, PIL I see only white canvas without any alpha channel

I started looking for the difference between these files, and those who open correctly and in ImageMagick saw this line `Alpha: srgba(255,255,255,0) #FFFFFF00` [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idzlD.png)

Valid files have `Alpha: srgba(0,0,0,0) #00000000`

File link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tN9D1vjwbnHg8urYJzHqI4zljS110oun/view?usp=sharing
Help:)

UPD. The question is closed. Files must be opened with the flag IMREAD_UNCHANGED

Comment: Your image has no alpha channel. The alpha channel was there at one time and the image was displayed where it replaced a checkerboard for the transparent areas. But it was then saved with the checkerboard in place of the alpha channel. So the alpha channel (transparency) cannot be recovered.

Comment: Nope. If you open this picture in any editor (Photoshop, etc.), there is transparency

Comment: Not the "example" link you posted! But graph.png does have transparency.

Comment: You dowload file and there is no transparency?

Comment: I talk about graph.png. Yep. Screenshot from ImageMagick

Comment: graph.png has transparency. But the image downloaded from "example" link does not have transparency. It has been replaced with an opaque checkerboard pattern.

Comment: My mistake. I'll fix the description, thanks.

Comment: In OpenCV, you have to open with the flag for unchanged. The cv2.imshow() will not show the transparency however. It is dumb about transparency. But you can do cv2.imwrite() and it will save the transparency if saved to PNG or TIFF (not JPG)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I completely forgot about IMREAD_UNCHANGED:( Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have written like this

```
cv2.imread('file.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```